# I'm trying to use an aggregate I've pulled from MongoDB, but a part of the data is being considered undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, express, axios

I'm trying to use this aggregate to pull orders together with the product from MongoDB, but the product data is being treated as undefined for some reason, even if it is shown correctly when I use `console.log()`.

Back code:

```
// GET ORDERS BY CUSTOMER
app.post('/getOrderByCustomer', async (req, res) => {
  const {customerId} = req.body
  const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(customerId);
  try {
    //EXEMPLO DE JOIN(aggregate) DE COMPRA(Order) COM PRODUTO(products)
    const customerOrders = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "Products",
          localField: "product_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "products"
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {customer_id: objectId}
      }
    ]);
    res.send({ status: 'ok', data: customerOrders })
  } catch (e) {
    res.send({ status: 'error', data: e});
  }
})
```

Front Code:

```
export default function Orders() {

  const { customer } = useContext(Context)
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState<Array<IOrder>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(customer._id !== ""){
      http.post('getOrderByCustomer', { customerId: customer._id })
      .then(res => (setOrders(res.data.data)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    
  },[customer])

  return(
    <>
      {orders.length === 0 ? 
      "" :
      <section>
        <p className={styles.title} onClick={() => console.log(orders[0])}>Show Orders</p>
        <p>lenght of orders: {orders.length}</p>
        {orders[0].Product[0]._id}
      </section>
      }
    </>
  )
};
```

Console.log() of the order with the product:

```
{
  _id: '649f5dbf6102a6298ca87b63',
  customer_id: '6455ef2d93e0845caf61b5c8',
  product_id: '6483b95220b153233677c8e3',
  data: '2023-06-30T22:56:56.956Z',
  products: Array(1)
}
customer_id
  :
  "6455ef2d93e0845caf61b5c8"
data
  :
  "2023-06-30T22:56:56.956Z"
product_id
  :
  "6483b95220b153233677c8e3"
products
  :
  Array(1)
0
  : {
    _id: '6483b95220b153233677c8e3',
    imagem: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAYwA…QgxrUoAY1qEE/DUrp/w+hmPamURzb6wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
    titulo: 'Cell Inspiron',
    descricao: 'Notebook da marca cell, devido a seu processado sn…mas, vem instalado com o sistema Linux de fabrica',
    preco: '2,899.99',
    …
  }
length
  :
  1[[Prototype]]:
  Array(0)
_id
  :
  "649f5dbf6102a6298ca87b63" [
    [Prototype]
  ]:
  Object
```

The error that appears whenever I try to use the product in the code, it works fine if I use the order's parameter instead of the product's.

The orders are working as expected, only the products are showing errors, I tried redoing my http request and the mongoose aggregate, but the error persisted.

> ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
>
> at Orders (http://localhost:3000/main.465c79da82d0b5c47a59.hot-update.js:60:34)
> at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27873:22)
> at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30755:24)
> at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32467:20)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17465:18)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17509:20)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17566:35)
> at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37440:11)
> at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36687:16)
> at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36610:9)

Comment: We need to see the code. Are you accessing `products.0` or `products[0]`, for example?

Comment: Kindly provide the code, logs and errors in plain text as `code format` and not in as images. Images are only used for UI screenshots, etc.

Comment: Done, please tell if there is more i can do to explain the problem better, im not very used to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the interface i use was calling the product using a different variable from the data i get from MongoDB using the API, so there was a mismatch and the type came as "undefined".

I solved by using the same variable i get from the API in the interface.

```js
import IProduct from "./IProduct"

export default interface IOrder {
  _id: string
  customer_id: string
  product_id: string
  date?: Date
  products: Array<IProduct>
}

//It is now products as in the console.log()
```